# C# Data Access Layer for both existing ADO.NET code and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an c# application that has a repository layer that accesses the database. I would like to support SQL Server as well - which could be done by writing a set of classes that use `System.Data.SqlClient` (the app already uses interfaces so this should be simple enough).

However I am considering using EF though in my new data layer.

My question is, my repository pattern for EF has a Get on it that looks like this:

```
   public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, 
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, 
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
            return orderBy(query);

        return query;
    }
```

Very useful for doing things like

```
repo.Get(x => x.MyColumn == "Value").ToList();
```

for example.

The apps existing data layer does something different which isn't as good but achieves a similar thing:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string whereSql = "", params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
```

I can't see any alternative but to replace these calls with specific repository methods e.g. `GetAllOrdersForCustomer(Guid customerId)` that way both data layers are achievable.

It appears those are my choices - write a SQL data layer for SQL Server, or modify the app to have specific repository patterns so I can support EF.

Has anyone any ideas on how I could perhaps use the former method to generate `WHERE` clauses? It's a better way in any case because its typed rather than having a string with a `WHERE` in it that could contain anything.

Comment: You don't need a "repository" layer, that's what EF is for. EF generates the SQL statements itself and executes them using ADO.NET. Using a low-level "generic" repository on top of a high-level ORM like EF is an ugly *anti*-pattern. In fact, DbSet is the repository implementation, DbContext is the multi-entity Unit-of-Work

Comment: Your problem shows why the "generic" repository is such an ugly antipattern. With LINQ you could just specify the conditions you want, and even combine multiple of them by chaining `Where()` clauses. Now, you can't even write a simple `Where`

Comment: The real choice is to *remove all this code* and just use EF. Use a *specialized repository* to abstract *specific* operations and validations. Read Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). That's nothing new, [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) is from 2009.

Comment: maybe also [this](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/cqrs-in-aspnet-core-3-1/) will be interesting to read

Comment: Why did you use a "repository" in the first place? Patterns are meant to solve specific problems in specific situations. A hammer is good nails, bad for screws. There's a *lot* of copypasta (not a typo) out there about 'best practices", and even some "frameworks" that add all faddy features to a web site whether they make sense or not

Comment: A repository was used to begin with because when the code was written EF did not exist. What if I want to support a database that EF does not support? Its a level of abstraction to allow for different databases rather than hard coding SQL code in with the business logic. I can't really remove the old code because all the customers of this package will then need upgrading to use SQL / Server which means they need IT department support to do that. I want to introduce SQL/Server and give them a choice. I also don't want to exclude older customers who don't want to upgrade to the latest features.

Answer (score 0):

It a shame that my comment is at the bottom and not visible unless you request to view more comments because my question was edited by someone and everybody apart from vasily.sib misunderstood the question. If the answer was just use EF I wouldn't have asked the question would I?

Its an existing repository layer that supports a database that EF does not support.

The only option I think I have is to remove the odd few places where I use the fancy WHERE methods, and replace these with the exact access path being requested, e.g.

repo.GetById or customerrepo.GetOrders

I didn't think there was a better answer but thought it was worth asking anyway :-)